# some of my images, my javascript and my bootstrap css won't work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have found a bunch of solutions and tried to implement them, but none of them solved the issue.
My java script code is in : assets/javascripts/application.js
My css for bootstrap is in : assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss
and my images are in: assets/images all of them are png.

I've included the rails_12factor gem in my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# Gem for encryption
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

# Gem for bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

I've also updated my environments/production.rb file

```
PROJECT::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

I also tried to add

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

to application.rb

per request adding my application.js

```
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
  });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you post application.js and application.css please?

Comment: done, although this works locally so I am not sure what good it will do

Comment: Oh, you've got code directly in your application.js instead of including other files.  What about application.css.  Can you post that?

Comment: my application.css is empty all of my css is in two files custom.css.scss and tasks.css.scss

Comment: So if it's empty, then how are you including your css files?

Comment: they are in the custom.css.scss and i have  *= require_self
 *= require_tree . in the application css

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38696/discussion-between-manishie-and-quantico)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images issue was solved by replacing html code `<img src= ""> with <%= image_tag("") %>`

bootstrap icons- had do download them directly from http://glyphicons.com/, and change my html  to   `<%= content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-user") %>`

javascript issue resolved itself afterward